# Bad requests for WordPress RSS and author URLs

Tags: wordpress, apache, http, rss

On a popular WordPress site, I'm getting a constant stream of requests for these paths (where `author-name` is the first and last name of one of the WordPress users):

```
GET /author/index.php?author=author-name HTTP/1.1

GET /index.rdf HTTP/1.0

GET /rss HTTP/1.1
```

The first two URLs don't exist, so the server is constantly returning 404 pages. The third is a redirect to `/feed`.

I suspect the requests are coming from RSS readers or search engine crawlers, but I don't know why they keep using these specific, nonexistent URLs. I don't link to them anywhere, as far as I can tell.

Does anybody know (1) where this traffic is coming from and (2) how I can stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Apache logs to get the "where" part.

Stopping random internet traffic is hard. Maybe serve them some other error codes and it will stop. It probably wont tho.

Most my sites have these, most of the time I track them to Asia or the americas, blocking the ip works but if they are few and far between that would be just wasting resources.